# prevent data reload from database into a from

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, forms, reload

My software is in ASP.NET and it is slow since it reloads all data from database into a form but I want only load updated or new data into the form and keep the rest untouched. I think caching could be a solution.

Any comment or ideas? What about other solutions.

Comment: Yes caching is an option. Look into using the built-in MemoryCache.

Comment: Use paging, and get only Page size data not much of that, 
use jquery to prevent service calls that make CPU usage heavy.
Use procedures in SQL .
Use Ajax call so the refresh data amount will be less. 
store images and data cache.